# Fixing a timer control knob on a microwave

Tags: timer

The timer control does not  register the proper time when we turn the knob. Can this be "home" fixed or not? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 possibilities:

#### Internal Timer Mechanism

If it is the internal timer mechanism - i.e., the electronics that respond to your mechanical turning of the knob - then it is likely not worth fixing.

#### Shaft

The timer knob slides onto a shaft. Typically that shaft will be metal, though in some cases it is plastic. If that shaft is deformed such that a "good" knob does not turn the shaft, then you are also likely out of luck - not worth fixing.

#### Knob

Fortunately, most of the time the problem is the knob itself. A typical inexpensive control knob will have a D-shaped hole that fits tightly over a D-shaped shaft. Over time, either the plastic "D" in the knob will erode, or a straight piece of plastic or metal that turns a circle into a "D" will break. The knobs are replaceable, and they don't have to match the name or color or style - the only parts that matter are  the size of the shaft and the total diameter of the knob. Google *replace d knob* for plenty of options. Many of us who grew up before every TV had a digital remote control (and before we could order replacement knobs on Amazon) remember having a pair of pliers on top of the TV with the broken knob to change channels.